# Google Cloud VPN connections from on-premise network

Tags: vpn, google-compute-engine

I have a project(Project A on 10.240.0.0)  on GCP and VPN connections through this Project.. All is fine.. Now, we have a new project(Project B on 10.35.0.0) other than the first one. Should I create a new VPN connection for the second project or can I use the existing one by adding the new VLAN IPs to the routes

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from your question is, you have a project in GCP which is connected to your on-prem using VPN, and now you have a second project which you need to connect to your on-prem. In that case yes, you should create a new VPN connection for Project B. You can see option 2 from the link [1] on how to create another VPN tunnel to your on-prem.

Or, you have more options, like you can connect your Project A and Project B using shared VPC [2] or VPC network peering [3] and your Project A is already connected to your on-prem using VPN, so in this way you don’t need to add an extra VPN tunnel for Project B.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/redundant-vpns#option-2
[2] https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc#shared_vpc_networks
[3] https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering#key_properties